Problem determining cuda/GPU as device for generator of LLM, always going back to CPU
Background: I am trying to finetune Microsoft's Phi-2 model which is a 2.5 billion parameter LLM published on HuggingFace with instruction tuning with a little over 2000 quotes. I want to create a recognizable output change due to the isntruction tuning. I want to later extract word embeddings from the base model and my finetuned model to compare them. I am working in a jupyter notebook with VS Code in a virtual environment and have access to a server with enough capacity to handle LLMs. I already sucessfulyy tokenized the data to feed into the model, loaded and tested the basic model and moved all to cuda/GPU defined as 'device'
HOWEVER, MY PROBLEM: when I try to feed the tokenized training and evalaution datasets into the model for training I get the following error message indicating that the generator is on cpu and not cuda as far as I understand:
ERROR MESSAGE
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[51], line 37 11 trainer = transformers.Trainer( 12 model=model, 13 train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset, (...) 33 data_collator=transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False), 34 ) 36 model.config.use_cache = False # silence the warnings. Please re-enable for inference! ---> 37 trainer.train()

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1780, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs) 1778 hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars() 1779 else: -> 1780 return inner_training_loop( 1781 args=args, 1782 resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint, 1783 trial=trial, 1784 ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval, 1785 )

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2085, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval) 2082 rng_to_sync = True 2084 step = -1 -> 2085 for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator): 2086 total_batched_samples += 1 2088 if self.args.include_num_input_tokens_seen:

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/data_loader.py:452, in DataLoaderShard.iter(self) 450 # We iterate one batch ahead to check when we are at the end 451 try: --> 452 current_batch = next(dataloader_iter) 453 except StopIteration: 454 yield

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:631, in BaseDataLoaderIter._next(self) 628 if self._sampler_iter is None: 629 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750) 630 self._reset() # type: ignore[call-arg] --> 631 data = self._next_data() 632 self._num_yielded += 1 633 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and
634 self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and
635 self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:674, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self) 673 def _next_data(self): --> 674 index = self._next_index() # may raise StopIteration 675 data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index) # may raise StopIteration 676 if self._pin_memory:

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:621, in _BaseDataLoaderIter._next_index(self) 620 def _next_index(self): --> 621 return next(self._sampler_iter)

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py:287, in BatchSampler.iter(self) 285 batch = [0] * self.batch_size 286 idx_in_batch = 0 --> 287 for idx in self.sampler: 288 batch[idx_in_batch] = idx 289 idx_in_batch += 1

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/data_loader.py:92, in SeedableRandomSampler.iter(self) 90 # print("Setting seed at epoch", self.epoch, seed) 91 self.generator.manual_seed(seed) ---> 92 yield from super().iter() 93 self.set_epoch(self.epoch + 1)

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py:167, in RandomSampler.iter(self) 165 else: 166 for _ in range(self.num_samples // n): --> 167 yield from torch.randperm(n, generator=generator).tolist() 168 yield from torch.randperm(n, generator=generator).tolist()[:self.num_samples % n]

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/device.py:77, in DeviceContext._torch_function(self, func, types, args, kwargs) 75 if func in _device_constructors() and kwargs.get('device') is None: 76 kwargs['device'] = self.device ---> 77 return func(args, *kwargs)

RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'

Additonally, I get he following warning:
Using the WANDB_DISABLED environment variable is deprecated and will be removed in v5. Use the --report_to flag to control the integrations used for logging result (for instance --report_to none). ./.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py:432: FutureWarning: Passing the following arguments to Accelerator is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0 of Accelerate: dict_keys(['dispatch_batches', 'split_batches', 'even_batches', 'use_seedable_sampler']). Please pass an accelerate.DataLoaderConfiguration instead: dataloader_config = DataLoaderConfiguration(dispatch_batches=None, split_batches=False, even_batches=True, use_seedable_sampler=True) warnings.warn( 
The code parts from my jupyter notebook relevant are the training:

#import wandb
import transformers
from datetime import datetime
import torch
torch.set_default_device("cuda")
project = "ideollm"
base_model_name = "phi2"
run_name = base_model_name + "-" + project
output_dir = "./" + run_name

trainer = transformers.Trainer(
model=model,
train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset,
eval_dataset=tokenized_val_dataset,
args=transformers.TrainingArguments(
output_dir=output_dir,
warmup_steps=1,
per_device_train_batch_size=2,
gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
max_steps=500,
learning_rate=2.5e-5, # Want a small lr for finetuning
optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
logging_steps=25,              # When to start reporting loss
logging_dir="./logs",        # Directory for storing logs
save_strategy="steps",       # Save the model checkpoint every logging step
save_steps=25,                # Save checkpoints every 50 steps
evaluation_strategy="steps", # Evaluate the model every logging step
eval_steps=25,               # Evaluate and save checkpoints every 50 steps
do_eval=True,                # Perform evaluation at the end of training
#report_to="wandb",  
#run_name=f"{run_name}-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')}"  
),
data_collator=transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False),
)

model.config.use_cache = False  # silence the warnings. Please re-enable for inference!
trainer.train()

AND BEFORE THE TOKENIZING:

import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

for i, tokens in tokenized_train_dataset.items():

        output_ids = model.generate(tokenized_train_dataset[i].cuda(), do_sample=True, max_new_tokens=270, early_stopping=True,)
        output = tokenizer.batch_decode(output_ids)
        print(output)

I tried:

Commenting out WANDB because it threw errors -no more error for this but the overall still does not run
Changing the tokenizer
Intentionally setting model and dataset to cuda
checking availability of cuda/GPU
changing from google colab to VS Code and server

I get the same error over and over even though I tried to change the device and the data processing. The model does not train at all.

I don’t know that error message itself. But I ran into troubles when I installed cuda after having the python libraries installed. Doing a clean install of all python libraries after having all cuda related stuff installed solved the problem for me.

So you mean to create a new virtual environment and before installing the Python librar y versions I need I should set cuda and define it as 'device'?

The python packages using cuda have a build step involved when installing them them that links them to cuda. But therefore cuda has to be installed before you install those packages.

If you want to use GPU specifically then you can set the device_map parameter like this: device_map={"0": "cuda:<GPU_id>", "1": "cuda:<GPU_id>", "2"}
To get the gpu id, you can run the below code
import torch
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print([i for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count())])
torch.cuda.device_count() to get the number of available CUDA devices and create a list of device IDs using a list comprehension. This method will give you the available GPU device IDs
